# Jersey JSON POJO Mapping with Moxy

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, moxy, jsonschema2pojo

I am working with Jersey Web services (2.23) and use POJO mapping for the JSON-to-Object mapping (Jersey-media-moxy). I created a class as follows:

```
public class DataPush {
    public String asset;
    public String timestamp;
    public Map<String,String> aspects;
}
```

I expected that instances of this object have the following structure:

```
{"asset":"abc","timestamp":"xxx","aspects":[{"key":"sdfasd","value":"sdfsd"},{"key":"sdddfasd","value":"sdfddsd"}]}
```

Indeed, a further element "entry" is generated:

```
{"asset":"sdf","timestamp":"sdfsd","aspects":{"entry":[{"key":"sdfasd","value":"sdfsd"},{"key":"sdddfasd","value":"sdfddsd"}]}}
```

What is the most easiest way to get rid of the "entries" element?
I know I could write my own mapping, however I hope that there is a easy solution to manage this..

Answer (score 1):

You can go to topic : 
Jackson JSON – Converting JSON to Map on journaldev.com.

https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct except the original question was for MOXy, not JacksonXML.